# How to escape special characters in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

```
 www.example.com/coaching/Run for 1(hr)
```

how can I escape () when using rewrite rule?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just use a \ character.

Answer (score 1):

I think those are just regexes, so a \ should escape the brackets

RewriteRule coaching/(Run) for (1\(hr\)) cgi-bin/log?activity=$1&duraction=$2

Something like that !

Comment: Should that not be a backslash?